# Converting non-unicode binary strings to byte array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, binary, non-unicode

I read a binary file using ajax from a web server. The HTTP response is of contentType: 'application/octet-stream' and contains a binary string that is just a string of bytes (not unicode), for example (in hex):

0x00 0x08 0x17 0xA1 0x01

Note: in C this would be represented as 5 bytes in memory:

```
char buf[5] = {0, 8, 23, 161, 1}
```

...but in Javascript that is a string which ASCII representation is something like "   � " (I can't actually paste it properly as not all characters have a printable representation).

I now need to convert this into an array of characters or integers so that I can access the numerical value of each character in the string. However iterating through the example string using the charCodeAt() function returns:

```
[0] 0
[1] 8
[2] 23
[3] 65533
[4] 1
```

because charCodeAt() decodes unicode characters, and 0xA1 is not recognised as valid unicode character so a [Replacement Character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm) (65533) is used instead.

I would like to get the following:

```
[0] 0
[1] 8
[2] 23
[3] 161
[4] 1
```

How to achieve this?

Here is the code snippet:

```
$.ajax({
url: url,
type: "get",
success: function(data) { // data contains binary representation of 0x00 0x08 0x17 0xA1 0x01
    var byteTab = []
    for (var n = 0; n < data.length; ++n) {
        byteTab.push(data.charCodeAt(n))
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** I'm not so sure [default] Ajax is the right tool for the job in this case. Regardless of file size, it is generally a good practice to use streams instead to accommodate future scalability, as your current method loads everything at once.

[This article](http://www.henryalgus.com/reading-binary-files-using-jquery-ajax/) goes over how to create a custom ajax transport that wraps an `XmlHttpRequest` to load the data into an array buffer rather. You could do this,  sequentially push the bytes into your main array, and go from there.

**Old:**
I'm not sure if I properly understood your data representation, but I believe you can just use `parseInt()` to turn a hex string into decimal:

```js
var data = ['0x00', '0x08', '0x17', '0xA1', '0x01'];
var parsed = [];

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 parsed.push(parseInt(data[i], 16));
}

console.log(parsed);
console.log(parseInt('0xA1', 16))
```

If this is not what you mean, please comment and I will try to update my answer with a more specific implementation.

Comment: Apologies if my question was not clear in that respect - I have now update the question.
The content of the "data" buffer returned from the web server in my code snippet is a string corresponding to 5 bytes. In C, this could be represented as as: char buf[5] = {0, 8, 23, 161, 1}. In Javascript this is returned as a string of length 5. Sine Javascript does not operate on "bytes" or "chars" like C, I can't find a way to get the numerical value of individual characters in this string since some like 0xA1 (161) are not unicode characters.

Answer (score 1):

Following the [suggestion](http://www.henryalgus.com/reading-binary-files-using-jquery-ajax/) from [Haus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9285560/haus) 's answer I found some more solutions to the problem so I will share my findings here.

1. My preferred solution is to use [ArrayBuffer](https://www.javascripture.com/ArrayBuffer) to access raw data. Unfortunately Ajax does not seem to support it as per [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394622/does-jquery-ajax-or-load-allow-for-responsetype-arraybuffer), although there is an option to add [support](http://www.henryalgus.com/reading-binary-files-using-jquery-ajax/) (which I could not get to work), and there is no straightforward way to create an ArrayBuffer out of string. However XMLHttpRequest supports ArrayBuffer as responseType as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data) so I changed my code to the following, which does what I want:

   ```
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open('GET', url);
   xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';  
   xhr.onload = function() {
       if (this.status == 200) {
           var byteTab=[]
           var uint8View = new Uint8Array(this.response)
           for (var n = 0; n < uint8View.byteLength; n++) {
               byteTab.push(uint8View[n])
           }

       } 
   };
   xhr.send();
   ```
2. Another solution is to get to ArrayBuffer via using Blob, which is explained with an example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45669951/4400655)
3. Another option is to use Blob in conjunction with FileReader.readAsBinaryString() along the lines of the example [here](https://www.javascripture.com/Blob). Using readAsBinaryString() converts the blob to a unicode string which can then be parsed using charCodeAt()